# Swift: How to make a Generic Class conform to a delegate protocol which its method has a Generic Type parameter?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a delegate protocol which its method requirement has a Generic Type parameter on it and I have a Generic Class which I want it to conforms to that delegate.

The problem is that I can't make that class to satisfy the requirement.

```
protocol ListDelegate: class {
  func list<T>(_ list: List<T>, didUpdatedItems items: [T])
}

class List<T> {
  var items: [T] {
    didSet {
      delegate?.list(self, didUpdatedItems: items)
    }
  }
  weak var delegate: ListDelegate?

  init(items: [T]) {
    self.items = items
  }
}

class ListWrapper<U>: ListDelegate {
  let list: List<U>
  var items: [U]

  init(list: List<U>) {
    self.list = list
    items = list.items
  }

  func list<T>(_ list: List<T>, didUpdatedItems items: [T]) {
    self.items = items
  }
}
```

The above code sample will result an error of `cannot assign value of type '[T]' to type '[U]'` but if I remove the `<T>` Generic Type from the requirement method implementation, it will results an error of `Type 'ListWrapper<U>' does not conform to protocol 'ListDelegate'`

How can I make a Generic Class to conform to that delegate?